# How can I prevent wordpress from sending emails

Tags: php, apache, spam, email

I would like to stop all email functionality in my wordpress installation.

Is this possible with a global flag?

or maybe by forbidding this installation to use the php `mail` function at all in htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link. It will may help you.

https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/1966437

Answer (score 0):

Below function is less offensive than overriding wp_mail(), and allows you to add extra logic when the emails should be disabled

```
function childtheme_no_emails( &$phpmailer ) {
    // Empty out the values that may be set
    $phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
    $phpmailer->ClearAttachments();
    $phpmailer->ClearCustomHeaders();
    $phpmailer->ClearReplyTos();
}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'childtheme_no_emails', 99, 1 );
```